# Change connection string for ASP.Net Identity Provider

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have a webforms application (Not MVC) that uses ClaimsIdentity.  I would like to dynamically switch connection strings, but I do not see a way to do this.  Everything I have seen on line, that references this, seems to be about MVC. Here is the code I have:

```
Dim userStore As New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)
Dim roleStore As New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)
Dim userManager As New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
Dim roleManager As New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(roleStore)

Dim userName As String = identity.Claims.First(Function(claim) claim.Type = ClaimTypes.WindowsAccountName).Value
```

Is there anyway to change which connection string I am using, instead of the DefaultConnection string found in the Web.config file?

**EDIT**

I have tried creating this class, to derive from:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports Application.Common
Imports Application.Data.Migrations
Imports Application.Models
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Namespace Application.Data
    Public Class ApplicationDbContext
        Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of IdentityUser)

        Public Sub New(ByVal stringName As String)
            MyBase.New(stringName, throwIfV1Schema:=False)
        End Sub


        Public Shared Function Create(ByVal stringName As String) As ApplicationDbContext
            Return New ApplicationDbContext(stringName)
        End Function

        Public Overloads Function [Set](Of TEntity As Class)() As IDbSet(Of TEntity)
            Return MyBase.[Set](Of TEntity)()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then, I do this:

```
Dim newContext As ApplicationDbContext = New ApplicationDbContext("test")

Dim userStore As New UserStore(newContext)
Dim roleStore As New RoleStore(newContext)
Dim userManager As New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
Dim roleManager As New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(roleStore)
```

But, the variables userStore and RoleStore of an error "To few arguements to 'UserStore' ..."

**EDIT**

Creating the managers, like this, worked:

```
 Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)(New ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnection1"))
 Dim roleStore = New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnection1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `IdentityDbContext` instance and set ConnectionString via constructor and then create `UserStore` and `RoleStore` with this instance and finally use them for creating `UserManager` and `RoleManager`.

I'm not so good at `VB`, here's what I mean in `C#`

```
string nameOrConnectionString = "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING";
var dbcontext = new IdentityDbContext(nameOrConnectionString);

var userStore = new UserStore(dbcontext);
var roleStore = new RoleStore(dbcontext);

var UserManager = new UserManager(roleStore);
var RoleManager = new RoleManager(roleStore);
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but I am not sure my new class is implemented correctly.  When I use it, I get an error.  Please see my updates for more information.  Can you tell me what my new ApplicationDbContext class should include?  Am I missing something?

Comment: And if it is in C#, that is fine.  I can translate it.

Comment: I just fixed it.  I had to implement like this:   

Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)(New ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnection1"))
            
Dim roleStore = New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnection1"))